# Disable Close button of the dialog window Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, modal-dialog

I need to disable close button of the dialog window like this: 
`errordlg`, `warndlg`, `msgbox`, `helpdlg`, `waitbar`. 
I found some information about `CloseRequestFcn`, but I do not know how to use it in the dialog box.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but here's a couple of ways how you could remove entire title bar, including the close button:

1) If you're using Windows, you can use [WindowsAPI](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31437-windowapi) mex function (you will need to compile it, or else download compiled version):

```
WindowAPI(gcf, 'Clip', true);
```

2) You can follow Yair's suggestion in his [Frameless (undecorated) figure windows](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/frameless-undecorated-figure-windows) article, basic idea behind which is setting `setUndecorated(true)` on underlying JFrame. Or else, simply use [undecorateFig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50111-undecoratefig-remove-restore-figure-border-and-title-bar) FEX function which does it for you.

Comment: Thank you for advice. But how i can use it in this code: 
`choice = questdlg(Question:', 'Name', '1', '2', '3','1');
            switch choice
                case '1'
                case '2'
                case '3'`

Comment: You need a figure handle to alter the appearance. Clearly this would not work with modal windows such as `questdlg`. You should use non-modal window, and get the result via a callback.